# Access user using passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js with the user strategy, when I console log req in my callback route I am getting the following part:

```
sessionStore: MemoryStore {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    disconnect: [Function: ondisconnect],
    connect: [Function: onconnect]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  sessions: [Object: null prototype] {
    'ssoT3fMSsf-d4xU9D0-SQPCaqOczzi_0': `{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"domain":"localhost","path":"/"},"passport":{"user":...`
  },
  generate: [Function]
},
sessionID: 'CyGF1bCHjA6yvdC4MFxMt0Msj5zc1624',
session: Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: 'localhost',
    secure: false
  }
},
_passport: {
  instance: Authenticator {
    _key: 'passport',
    _strategies: [Object],
    _serializers: [Array],
    _deserializers: [Array],
    _infoTransformers: [],
    _framework: [Object],
    _userProperty: 'user',
    _sm: [SessionManager],
    Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
    Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
    Strategy: [Function],
    strategies: [Object]
  }
```

My question is how can I send back the user? I tried

```
passport.use(
  new Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET!,
      callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: ["identify", "guilds"],
    },
    (_, __, profile, cb) => cb(null, profile)
  )
)

passport.serializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, id)
})

return res.send({ user: req.session.passport.user })
```

but without success, I am just not sure how to access the user but it is there

Answer (score 0):

One way I tried to get user is through serialization and deserialization methods.
You can read more about from [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/)

```
const express=require('express');
const expressSsn=require('express-session');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const app= express();
const passport = require('passport');
const localstrategy = require('passport-Local').Strategy;
const user =require("../passport-demo/user");

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(expressSsn({
secret : 'ok',
saveUninitialized : false,
resave : true,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(usr,done){
   console.log("Serialized method");
   done(null,usr.token);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(usr,done){

console.log("Deserialized method");
if(usr==user.token)
{
    console.log("Get Called  = ");
    done(null,user);
}
else
{
    console.log("Token not matched");
    done(null,false);
}
});

passport.use(new localstrategy(
{
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
},
function(username,password,done)
{
        if(username == user.username && password == user.password)
        {
            console.log("Correct Password");
            return done(null,user,{message : 'correct Password' });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Incorrect Password");
            return done(null,false);
        }
}
));

app.post('/',function(req,res,err)
{
   console.log(user);
   res.end();
});

app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local')
   ,function (req,res,err)
   {
            res.send("Request : "+req.user.username);
});

app.post('/data',function(req,res,err)
{
  console.log(req.user);
  res.end();
});


app.listen(3000,console.log('host is running at 3000'));
```

Comment: I have edited the code, I had this already except for the discord strategy, as you can see the user is there but I am just not sure how to access it

Comment: put this line in deserializeUser console.log('user',req.id),and see if you can get user id

Answer (score 0):

### As per [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/) documentations :

By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a `401 Unauthorized`status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked. If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the `req.user` property will be set to the authenticated user.

#### So you can get the user as  `req.user`

Comment: req.user returns undefined for me, the only part where I see user in the request is in the 9th line of my question

Comment: So you can set user by userself after authentication set req.user from the result.